# Chrome blocking javascript from extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

When I open up the JavaScript console in chrome while running an extension I made, an error saying that JavaScript could not be run due to security reasons is shown. Is there something I should add to my manifest file to make it work?

This is the default manifest that I downloaded from http://extensionizr.com/

```
    {
  "name": "",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "",
  "homepage_url": "",
  "icons": {
    "16": "icons/icon16.png",
    "48": "icons/icon48.png",
    "128": "icons/icon128.png"
  },
  "default_locale": "en",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icons/icon19.png",
    "default_title": "",
    "default_popup": "src/browser_action/browser_action.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "http://localhost/*"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "https://www.google.com/*"
      ],
      "css": [
        "src/inject/inject.css"
      ]
    },
    {
      "matches": [
        "https://www.google.com/*"
      ],
      "js": [
        "src/inject/inject.js"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the manifest.json file? What are your permissions set as? What are you doing in your script?

Comment: which console: the popup, the background, the page?

Comment: The extension is to hide any 'a' html element that has "foobar" in the text. I added the manifest I have been using.

Answer (score 0):

Your content_scripts are set to inject when your page is on a 'google.com/*' site but you've only given it permission for a 'localhost/*' site. Why not change your permissions to

```
"permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ],
```

so that you have access to whichever tab you are testing?

Otherwise, change your content_scripts.matches to the location you've allowed in permissions.